# RestKit and Tastypie integration

Tags: restkit, tastypie

I'm using RestKit to access a Tastypie API.  I have control of both ends.

I have configured RestKit mapping to successfully load a "naked" JSON resource at `/api/v1/organizations/1/ like this:

```
{
"id": "1", 
"name": "ACME Space"
}
```

But how do I configure RestKit to load a resource at `/api/v1/organizations/` that looks like this:

```
{
"meta": 
    {
        "limit": 20, 
        "next": null, 
        "offset": 0, 
        "previous": null, 
        "total_count": 2
    }, 
"objects": 
    [
        {
            "id": "1", 
            "name": "ACME Space"
        },
        {
            "id": "2", 
            "name": "XYZ Tech"
        }
    ]
}
```

I assume that RestKit doesn't like the `meta` key or the `objects` key being used for an `Organization` object.

I'm trying to do this with a `RKFetchedResultsTableController`.  Is there a delegate callback that I can override or a class I can subclass to strip away the extra JSON that RestKit doesn't like?  Is it perhaps easier to change the way Tastypie emits the JSON response?

This question is similar to [this unanswered SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384010/integration-of-restkit-with-django-tastypie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you take a look at the feature/reboot-networking-layer branch that is currently in the late stages of development. One of the many features in there is a harmonization of key-path and URL based mapping configurations using a new class called `RKResponseDescriptor`. Basically this lets you say, when I load an object at this path pattern (in this case, /api/v1/organizations) map the 'objects' key path using the given mapping. This works around previous problems with key path ambiguity for generic key paths like 'objects'.

There is extensive documentation in the headers (published at http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0-dev/index.html) and a new README.md published to https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/tree/feature/reboot-networking-layer.

Comment: I'll take a look at that branch tonight Blake -- it sounds promising.  I'd really like to fix this impedance mismatch between RestKit and Tastypie on the RestKit side as I may not always be able to control the API.

Also -- thanks for your quick response.  It is always great when a framework developer answers questions.

Comment: The PATCH support alone makes this worth looking at closer!

Comment: You sure have a lot of great features packed into 0.20.  It looks great, but I'm afraid that it means rewriting a lot of code - and for a development release.  I've already started a new branch of my code, but it might be nice to find an interim solution for my small issue in the question without having to switch to 0.20.

Answer (score 0):

The development version of TastyPie has a `Meta.collection_name` attribute you can use to distinguish.  See the [documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#collection-name) here.

With that in place, I created a `Meta` class and mapped it `forKeyPath:@"meta"` and RestKit figured out the rest.  I get object lists back with one Meta object and N of my actual objects.